# Send notification/email 7 days before given date

Tags: excel, email, notifications, ms-office

I have table with employees. It contains some information and also date of birth. Is it possible to send notification/email (directly from excel) let's say 7 days in advance to know that he/she will have birthday soon?

I found some tutorials, but all require Visual Basic. Unfortunately, it is for my sister without any knowledge of programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this via Word's mail merge feature. But since this would require quite a few manual steps (presumably on a daily/weekly basis), I'm afraid it's not what your sister is after. You could code a similar feature in VBA but that would still require her to open the document regularly to run the macro so perhaps it would be quicker and simpler to just check a filtered employee list.

If you want a closer look at mail merge, try [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Sort-and-filter-data-for-a-mail-merge-AF9F7912-5E1D-40A6-A52A-F41ECCF98B8E?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). You could use a helper column to identify which birthdays are close (e.g. using [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-day-of-year)) and filter on that column, then you show only those whose birthdays are in the next x days.